# Issue regarding python and pip

Tags: python, selenium, pip, pycharm, pytest

I am trying to install selenium pytest etc on pycharm, unable to do so getting an error as "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium". I have python 3.9 and pip 3

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which version of Selenium are you currently using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force upgrade selenium using *`pip3`* as follows:

```
pip3 install -U selenium
```